# Rounding up decimal value in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rounding

I have used `Math.Round` function for rounding up the decimal value but somehow the result I am getting are not as I want. I want the result something like this

if value is 1234.50 or if value after the decimal point is greater than 50 then the value I should get is 1235. If the value after decimal point is less than 50 the i should get 1234 like 1234.49 then i should get 1234.

Using Math.Round is giving me 1234 when my value is 1234.51. Is there any other function than i can use for my query.?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Can you give code because what you are asking is banker's rounding and .net does that by default.

Answer (score 5):

```
Math.Round(Decimal, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

By default Math.Round uses `MidpointRounding.ToEven`(Banker's round) wich round to the nearest even number.

Comment: How can i use this function to round 1234.51.? I mean I am using thisMath.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(1234.51)).How to use the fucntion that you mentioned.?